# How do I change the color of the keyboard to dark mode for android in React Native?

Tags: react-native, user-interface

I know that the `keyboardAppearance"` prop for `TextInput` sets an ios keyboard to dark mode, but how could I do this for android too? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do it on android.

In Android the keyboard is not (only) a native feature. You can chose wether showing it or not and which keyboard to show.

But since it's another application, you can't access it directly, the only tasks you can do are opening the app with intent.

However, the iOS, which is ironically more closed to OS tweaks, is available:

[image]